# How to sort computed values in a v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `v-data-table` from Vuetify in my Vue.js app.
The table has a column of computed values.
I wanna make that column sortable.
What do I have to do?

What I tried:
I was looking into the sort function of the [v-data-table-header](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props).
It offers: `sort?: (a: any, b: any) => number`.

However, when I define that function for my column the values in the column are still not sorted.

HTML:

```
<v-data-table
    :headers='headers'
    :items='items'
>
    <template v-slot:item.complete='{ item }'>
        <span v-if='!isComplete(item)' class='error--text'>not complete</span>
        <span v-else>complete</span>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Script:

```
readonly headers: DataTableHeader[] = [
    {
      text: 'Completeness',
      value: 'complete',
      sort: (a, b) => {
        console.log(a, b);
        return 1;
      }
    },
  ];

items = [
  {
    name: "foo",
    tasks: 3
  },
  {
    name: "bar",
    tasks: 42
  }
]

isComplete(item: any): boolean {
  return 12 <= item.tasks && item.tasks <= 50;
}
```

The order doesn't change when I enable sorting and the log says:

```
undefined undefined
undefined undefined
undefined undefined
...
```

What do I need to do to sort computed values?

Comment: Why don't you just include your "computed" prop into **items**? By example, [this way in CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/NWaRREy) (take a look into _mounted_ stage)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can sort computed data in a table unless the objects inside `items` array each have a field called `complete` with some value, because that's what the table is looking for to get the value (hence `undefined`).